# Can I make the background of the android application as group of images?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-background

I need help in make the background of my app as gallery of photos... is that possible? and how to do that?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? You want the images as slideshow in the background or collage or what is the exact use case?

Comment: you can use relative layout and add gridview in it , then add above the gridview , the rest of views

Comment: Hope [this article](http://javatechig.com/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android) helps.

Comment: yes you can say like slideshow, I mean I want to create controls and stuff and everything ..but the background keep changing with specific pictures @SayaleePote

Comment: thank you, I will try that @NayraAhmed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a **GridView** to show images in column and row fashion. For more information you can take a look at [this article for implementing gridview](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by assigning an `id` to your parent layout and then in java you can change the background image after a certain action is performed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Asyymmetric Gridview to achive attractive view of gallery

you can use [this](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid) library

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can I did it before by creating an animation that contain the images then I set this animation as backgroud

```
        // Type casting the Image View
    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    // Setting animation_list.xml as the background of the image view
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.animation);

    // Type casting the Animation drawable
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
    frameAnimation.start();
```

example animation xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_1" android:duration="3000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_2" android:duration="3000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_3" android:duration="3000" />   

</animation-list>
```

Comment: (R.anim.animation)   what is "animation?

Comment: It's the ID of animation that contain the images as describe in Its xml, every image keep displaying 3 seconds then the next ... check this link http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html